# converting object value into float in python

Tags: python, django

i got timestamp returned as a tuple  from rrd database i.e. info variable will contain this

> [(38177492.733055562,
>   38177482.886388876),(39370533.190833323, 40563588.018611118)]

inside my code i am converting tuple (38177492.733055562,38177482.886388876) intto list using 
list function after that i am accessing element using "index" variable and when i am passing this value to fromtimestamp function it is asking me the "float" value so how can i convert list object into float primitive data type ? following is the whole code

```
def hello(request):

        info = rrdtool.fetch('hello/test.rrd','AVERAGE','-r','3600','-s','1298264400','-e','1298350800')

    datalist = list()
    for index in range(0,len(info)):    
         val = list(info[index])
         dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(val[index]))
         str=dt_obj.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")     
         datalist.append(str)

        data = simplejson.dumps(info, indent=4)
        return HttpResponse(data,mimetype='application/javascript')
```

i am getting following error

```
a float is required
```

after changing code to for index in range(0,len(info)): i am getting following error

```
invalid literal for float(): Out
```

Comment: Did you confirm that you are getting the expected list of tuples from your rrdtool.fetch()? try printing out info after fetching.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing doesn't make much sense, I'm afraid - `index` is an index into the `info` list, not into `val`, which is one of the tuples in that list.

Also, you don't need to convert the list into a tuple in order to access an element of the tuple.

Your indentation is broken in the line where the loop starts, and also when you outdent to return a json version of `info`.

To work out your problem, you could start by printing `val`, `val[index]` and `type(val[index])` on the line before your error to check that they are what you're expecting them to be - clearly they're not from the error you get.

Also, you don't need to use the index into the info list at all, you could iterate over the values in the list with:

```
for val in info:
    # I'm not sure if you want both values in the tuple here or just one...
    print >> sys.stderr, "val =", val
    dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(val[0])
    str=dt_obj.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")     
    datalist.append(str)
```

Comment: i am getting a float is required error on line dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(val[0])

Comment: @Hunt: right.  So, if you're running this with `./manage.py runserver` you should see the output from the `print >> sys.stderr` line in the log - what does it say?